# How to write a test cases for a function in jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have created a function and I want to write a test case for that function. I am returning HTML content in that function.

my function code is -

```
export function executeScenario(handleExecuteScenarioClick: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined, classes: any , buttonTitle:string) {
  return <Button id="executescenario" variant="contained" onClick={handleExecuteScenarioClick} type="button" className={classes.button} color="primary">
    {buttonTitle}
  </Button>;
}
```

I am using enzyme and jest and I wanna test this function and return a button to be true.
How can I write test case for this function ?

Comment: What do you want to test? That is returns a React Element? Something else? Please narrow your question to a more specific issue and include expected result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Are you using enzyme and jest?

Comment: Yes I am using enzyme and jest and I wanna test this function and return a button to be true.

Comment: @wentjun I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: @Drew Reese Please check my question now

Answer (score 1):

you could use React testing library and write a test like this:

```
import { render, fireEvent, wait } from '@testing-library/react'

const { getByTestId } = render(<executeScenario {...props} />)

expect(getByTestId("executescenario")).toBeInTheDocument()
```

this is expecting to find this element with the mentioned `id` on the page. for the full docs and other stuff you can do, check out the docs here: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro

Comment: We can not render a function . It is throwing error

Comment: OP isn't rendering a functional component, and would need to use `data-testid=".."` for `getByTestId` to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Enzyme and Jest, you can test for the above by shallow rendering the component, following by checking if `Button` is rendered by using the [find](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) method.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<executeScenario buttonTitle='sample' classes='primary' />); // include the required props
const button = wrapper.find(Button);
expect(button).toHaveLength(1);
```

Comment: No overload matches this call on executeScenario. Getting this error.

Comment: Now it is saying no argument is passed

Comment: Oh, I just realised `executeScenario ` is a component.. Edited.

Comment: it's a function. So now can you again tell me